# How to fix multiple video source playing error on videojs

Tags: javascript, json, video.js

I am trying to add multiple video source using this JavaScript file:

```
var herf=location.href,x=herf,data=new FormData;data.append("im",x);var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("POST","/json.php"),xhr.responseType = 'json',xhr.onload=function(){
var e=this.response;
 const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).flashvars.metadata;
 const video = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(obj))).videos; 
 for (let i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
 url = video[i].url;
 name = video[i].name;
 if(name == "mobile"){
    var a = "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '144p',res: 144},"
 } else if(name=="lowest"){
    var b = "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '240p',res: 240},"
 } else if(name=="low"){
    var c = "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '360p',res: 360},"
 } else if(name=="sd"){
    var d = "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '480p',res: 480},"
 } else if(name=="hd"){
    var e = "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '720p',res: 720},"
 } else if(name=="full"){
    var f = "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '1080p',res: 1080},"
 } else if(name=="quad"){
    var g ="{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '2k',res: 2048},"
 } else if(name=="ultra"){
    var h= "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '4k',res: 4096}"
 }else{
    var j = null;
  }  
 }
 var allsource = a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h;
 var sources = allsource.replaceAll("undefined","");
 const player = VideoJs('player');
 player.src([sources]);
//document.write(source);
},xhr.send(data);
```

It returns source something like this:

```
var sources = "[
                   {
                      src = 'http://example.com/720p.mp4'
                      lable = '720p'
                      type = 'video/mp4'
                   },
                   {
                      src = 'http://example.com/1080p.mp4'
                      lable = '1080p'
                      type = 'video/mp4'
                   }
                   {
                      src = 'http://example.com/2048p.mp4'
                      lable = '2048p'
                      type = 'video/mp4'
                   }
               ]"
```

But it should be something like this:

```
var sources = [
                   {
                      src = 'http://example.com/720p.mp4'
                      lable = '720p'
                      type = 'video/mp4'
                   },
                   {
                      src = 'http://example.com/1080p.mp4'
                      lable = '1080p'
                      type = 'video/mp4'
                   }
                   {
                      src = 'http://example.com/2048p.mp4'
                      lable = '2048p'
                      type = 'video/mp4'
                   }
               ]
```

Because the player.src() function need array file from the source property.
And in the end, I'm getting an error (No compatible source was found for this media).  I am using **videojs**.

**How can i fix it? Some can give me the solution??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to something like this

```
 const array = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
 url = video[i].url;
 name = video[i].name;
 const base = {src: url,type: "video/mp4"};
 if(name == "mobile"){  
      array.push({...base,label:"144p"})
   } else if(name=="lowest"){
      array.push({...base,label:"240p"})
   } else if(name=="low"){
      array.push({...base,label:"360p"})
   } else if(name=="sd"){
      array.push({...base,label:"480p"})
   } else if(name=="hd"){    
      array.push({...base,label:"720p"})
   } else if(name=="full"){
      array.push({...base,label:"1080p"})
   } else if(name=="quad"){
      array.push({...base,label:"2k"})
   } else if(name=="ultra"){    
      array.push({...base,label:"4k"})
   }
 }
 const playersrc = videojs('player',{}, function() {
     var player = this;
     player.controlBar.addChild('QualitySelector');
  });
   playersrc.src(array);
   console.log(array);
```

Now it's working

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

````
```javascript
var herf=location.href,x=herf,data=new FormData;data.append("im",x);var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("POST","/json.php"),xhr.responseType = 'json',xhr.onload=function(){
    var e=this.response;
     const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).flashvars.metadata;
     const video = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(obj))).videos; 
//Changes from here
     const sources = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
     url = video[i].url;
     name = video[i].name;
    
     const base = { src: url,type: 'video/mp4' }
     if(name == "mobile"){
        
        sources.push({...base, label: '144p',res: 144})
    
     } else if(name=="lowest"){
        var b = "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '240p',res: 240},"
        sources.push({...base, label: '240p',res: 240})
    
     } else if(name=="low"){
        var c = "{src: '"+url+"',type: 'video/mp4',label: '360p',res: 360},"
        sources.push({...base, label: '360p',res: 360p})
    
     }  
     }
     
    
     const player = VideoJs('player');
     player.src(sources);
    //document.write(source);
    },xhr.send(data);

I do not have experience with VideoJs, but would something like the above work for you ?
````

Comment: You'd need to declare `sources` outside the for loop

Comment: Yes misterben. You are right. And Thank you Zurez for your valuable answer...